# Is it really necessary to have a litter box for every cat? If so, why?

Tags: cats, health, toilet-training

I've always been told that I should have as many litter boxes as I do cats. I'm wondering if this is medically-based or is it personal pet preference (as I've heard that some cats merely won't share boxes with other cats).

Comment: Actually it one more litter box then number of cats

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your cats. I have never had more than two cats at the same time, and I had two litter boxes, but my cats only used one of them.

The reason for having one box per cat is to let a cat use it undisturbed by the other cat, and it is easier to avoid the litter being wet if you have two boxes.

If your cats only use one of the litter boxes, you only need one. If the cats want a private litter box, you use two.

One of the most common problems with only one litter box is a silent fight for domination where one cat starts to spray around the litter box. I am not saying this will happen, but it might happen.